# PHP cache control doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, caching, optimization, http-headers

Please take a look at my website:[vynora](http://www.vynora.com/)

**It's not finished.**  I have put a PHP header in the top of my HTML page:

```
<?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=6000");
?>
```

When I go to pagespeed of Google it tells me that I should optimize my browser cache, please take a look:[Google pagespeed](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/#url=http_3A_2F_2Fwww.vynora.com_2F&mobile=false)

But I already did using PHP. So how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem not in this page and not in PHP scripts. See Google's suggestions:

> The following cacheable resources have
>   a short freshness lifetime. Specify an
>   expiration at least one week in the
>   future for the following resources:
>
> - http://www.vynora.com/arrow.png (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/bing.png (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/dailymotion.png (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/dd_arrow.gif (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/deviantart.png (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/flickr.png (expiration not specified)
> - http://www.vynora.com/google.png (expiration not specified)
> - ...

It means, you should cache your **static** files.
As I can see, you use Apache. In this case you can use [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

For example, you can add into `.htaccess` file this lines:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
```

Comment: Hi, I have been looking for the .htaccess on my server but I can't find it....Could it be that I have delete it by accident?? Is this possible? How do I make a new one. I tried it with notepad and saving it as .htaccess When I place it next to my index.php the webpage doesn't function (error) When I put it in the root (next to public file mail etc) it doesnt do anything.

Comment: @yomoore, this file should be in same folder where index.php file is placed, use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or some IDE (netbeans, PhpStorm), don't use Notepad (he adds invisible stupid symbols in start of file).

Comment: It works now:) I downloaded notepad++ and copyd your text. And I also removed the php...Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

To cache page into users browser add theses headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=6000, pre-check=6000");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s"). " GMT");
```

gZip:

`http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/?url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy52eW5vcmEuY29tLw==`

says its gzipped

`http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vynora.com%2F`

says its gzipped

Comment: How is this any different from what I already have? It looks to me its the same.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work because there is possible whitespace before header(). 
Try it like this:

```
<?php 
    if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) {
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
    } else {
        ob_start();
    }
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=6000");
?>
```

You should set the expired header as well, because old browsers do not understand "max-age".

Btw.: Your server is currently sending "max-age: 0".

Comment: What do you mean by ''Your server is currently sending "max-age: 0"'' How did you check this?

Comment: Get the LiveHttpHeaders plugin for Firefox. Update: Ah now its 6000. :)