# Site cache is disabled, but can't figure out where it's getting disabled?

Tags: php, html, caching

My PHP site's HTML `<head>` tag includes:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=300"/>
```

Yet the headers show:

```
 Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
        check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
```

I can't find anywhere in the PHP site that I've inherited that is disabling the cache (I did a full file-content search for "cache" and did not find anything relevant).

I'm not sure where else to look, so I wanted to ask **what are all the different ways that caching can be disabled in a PHP site?**

Comment: Don't use the meta cache control, as it's useless. [Rather use header tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following at the top of the page - if this fixes it - then maybe check your .htaccess or somewhere in the control panel / php.ini - just guessing there..

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=6000, pre-check=6000"); 
header("Pragma: private"); 
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s"). " GMT");
```

Source: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161864/php-cache-control-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Author: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone)